# how to read data (using pandas?) so that it is correctly formatted?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a txt file with following format:

```
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"datalogger","columns":["time","ActivePower0","CosPhi0","CurrentRms0","DcAnalog5","FiringAngle0","IrTemperature0","Lage 1_Angle1","Lage 1_Angle2","PotentioMeter0","Rotation0","SNR","TNR","Temperature0","Temperature3","Temperature_MAX31855_0","Temperature_MAX31855_3","Vibra0_X","Vibra0_Y","Vibra0_Z","VoltageAccu0","VoltageRms0"],"values":[["2017-10-06T08:50:25.347Z",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"41762721","Testcustomer",null,null,null,null,-196,196,-196,null,null],["2017-10-06T08:50:25.348Z",null,null,null,null,null,null,346.2964,76.11179,null,null,"41762721","Testcustomer",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],["2017-10-06T08:50:25.349Z",null,null,2596,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"41762721","Testkunde",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,80700],["2017-10-06T08:50:25.35Z",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,1956,"41762721","Testkunde",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],["2017-10-06T09:20:05.742Z",null,null,null,null,null,67.98999,null,null,null,null,"41762721","Testkunde",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]}]}]}
...
```

So in the text file everything is saved in one line. CSV file is not available.
I would like to have it as a data frame in pandas. when I use read.csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('time-series-data.txt', sep = ",")
```

the output of print(df) is someting like [0 rows x 3455.. columns]
So currently everything is read in as one line. However, I would like to have 22 columns (time, activepower0, CosPhi0,..).  I ask for tips, thank you very much.

Is a pandas dataframe even suitable for this? the text files are up to 2 GB in size.

Comment: `read_csv` is for CSV files, which clearly doesn't apply here. You probably need `read_json`.

Comment: Please ensure `{ }` and `[ ]` are correctly balanced for results and values to be a right sample.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with read_json! I did not know that..

Comment: The sample data is not is not valid python or json. Please ensure a valid subset so someone can try out a solution for real data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example which can read the file you posted.

Here's the test file, named test.json:

```
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"datalogger","columns":["time","ActivePower0","CosPhi0","CurrentRms0","DcAnalog5","FiringAngle0","IrTemperature0","Lage 1_Angle1","Lage 1_Angle2","PotentioMeter0","Rotation0","SNR","TNR","Temperature0","Temperature3","Temperature_MAX31855_0","Temperature_MAX31855_3","Vibra0_X","Vibra0_Y","Vibra0_Z","VoltageAccu0","VoltageRms0"],

"values":[
["2017-10-06T08:50:25.347Z",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"41762721","Test-customer",null,null,null,null,-196,196,-196,null,null],
["2017-10-06T08:50:25.348Z",null,null,null,null,null,null,346.2964,76.11179,null,null,"41762721","Test-customer",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]}]}]}
```

Here's the python code used to read it in:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

# Read test file.
# This reads the entire file into memory at once. If this is not
# possible for you, you may want to look into something like ijson:
#    https://pypi.org/project/ijson/
with open("test.json", "rb") as f
    data = json.load(f)
# Get the first element of results list, and first element of series list
# You may need a loop here, if your real data has more than one of these.
subset = data['results'][0]['series'][0]
values = subset['values']
columns = subset['columns']
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns)
print(df)
```